# Is it safe to install Python 3 in CentOS Linux 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, python3

I just realised that the default Python version in CentOS Linux 7 is 2.7.5. I want to use Python 3 in CentOS. I'm not willing to install Anaconda as I'm running the OS on a VM (limited RAM and storage).

Can I install Python 3 using yum? I used to use Ubuntu, and I remembered that messing with Python versions in Ubuntu can mess up the system. Is it the same case with CentOS? How do I safely install Python 3 on CentOS?

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 7 supports installing python 2 and python 3 simultaneously. Use

```
yum install python3
```

for the installation. Note that the `python` command invokes python 2. The command for python3 is `python3`.